How to get EXIF info from a video file by using Exif-js
I am trying to get EXIF data from a mp4 file using exif-js with vain.
My code is attached below.
Image part works fine, but video part does NOT.
https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js?tab=readme-ov-file
According to the exif-js page, XMP is supported by calling EXIF.enableXmp();,
I put it before a call to get EXIF data from a mp4 file.
As far as I know XMP is used for storing meta (like EXIF) data in video files.
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-equivalent-of-EXIF-for-videos-What-are-easy-ways-to-view-the-data
Any idea about how to fix the code?
Thank you very much!
Have a nice weekend :)
Warm Regards,
DoKtor.
Update:
There seems it is not common to have "Make" and "Model" for meta data in videos,
so I have just chosen GPS Latitude which seems more common both in jpg and mp4.
exiftool outputs are added at the end.
You can try this code: http://doc.uk.to/test/
and download the contents test.jpg and test.mp4 as well.
These contents are actually taken by me by the way, please enjoy them :)
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<title> EXIF movies test </title>
</head>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
window.onload=getExif;

function getExif() {
    var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
    EXIF.getData(img1, function() {
        var make = EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
        var model = EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
        var GpsLatitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
        var makeAndModel = document.getElementById("makeAndModel");
        makeAndModel.innerHTML = `${make} ${model} ${GpsLatitude}`;
    });

    EXIF.enableXmp();
    var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
    EXIF.getData(img2, function() {
        var myData =this;
        var make = "A";  //EXIF.getTag(this, "Make");
        var model = "B"; //EXIF.getTag(this, "Model");
        var GpsLatitude = EXIF.getTag(this, "GPSLatitude");
        var makeAndModel2 = document.getElementById("makeAndModel2");
        makeAndModel2.innerHTML = `${make} ${model} ${GpsLatitude}`;

        var allMetaData = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
        var allMetaDataSpan = document.getElementById("allMetaDataSpan");
        allMetaDataSpan.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(allMetaData, null, "\t");
    });
}
</script>

<body>
<img width=400 src="test.jpg" id="img1" />
<pre>Make and model: <span id="makeAndModel"></span></pre>
<br/>

<!--<img src="test.mp4" id="img2" />-->

<!--
<video id="img2" autoplay muted width="560" height="315" controls >
  <source src="test.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></video>
-->

<iframe id= "img2" width="560" height="315" src="test.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<pre>Make and model2: <span id="makeAndModel2"></span></pre>
<pre id="allMetaDataSpan"></pre>

<br/>

</body>
</html>



$ exiftool test.jpg | grep "GPS Latitude"
GPS Latitude Ref                : South
GPS Latitude                    : 3 deg 8' 50.92" S

$ exiftool test.mp4 | grep "GPS Latitude"
GPS Latitude                    : 24 deg 19' 55.51" N
GPS Latitude Ref                : North


"but video part does NOT" - have you even verified that your file contains XMP (or Exif) to begin with? Which format(s) does f.e. ExifTool report?

Thank you very much for your comment. Yes, I did. Tested with exiftool which printed exif data with no problem. Tested on ubuntu 20.04.

Include that output into your question so we can be sure it's actually Exif or XMP and not another metadata format.

Thank you very much for your reply. All right, I wireply. All right, I will update my post and add the output of exiftool accordingly.

@AmigoJack Please take a look at my update. Thank you very much! Have a nice day!

No, use verbose output (at least -v1) and don't combine with grep or other tools - otherwise we don't see where the metadata comes from.

No, both file's metadata formats differ:

exiftool -v2 http://doc.uk.to/test/test.jpg produces the following output (irrelevant lines substituted with ...):

JPEG APP1 (13812 bytes):
  ExifByteOrder = MM
  + [IFD0 directory with 14 entries]
...
  | 11) GPSInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  |     - Tag 0x8825 (4 bytes, int32u[1])
  | + [GPS directory with 4 entries]
  | | 0)  GPSLatitudeRef = S
  | |     - Tag 0x0001 (2 bytes, string[2])
  | | 1)  GPSLatitude = 3 8 50.9153713 (3/1 8/1 509153713/10000000)
  | |     - Tag 0x0002 (24 bytes, rational64u[3])
  | | 2)  GPSLongitudeRef = E
  | |     - Tag 0x0003 (2 bytes, string[2])
  | | 3)  GPSLongitude = 35 33 24.05090632 (35/1 33/1 2405090632/100000000)
  | |     - Tag 0x0004 (24 bytes, rational64u[3])
...


That means the JFIF file contains

an APP1 segment which identifies as Exif.

Its directory (IFD0) 12th entry (counting starts with 0) points to a GPS directory,

which has 4 entries for each GPS detail.






exiftool -v2 http://doc.uk.to/test/test.mp4 produces:

...
  XMP (SubDirectory) -->
  - Tag 'uuid' (2883 bytes)
  + [XMP directory, 2867 bytes]
  | XMPToolkit = Image::ExifTool 12.76
  | GPSLatitude = 24,19.92517515N
  | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/exif:GPSLatitude'
  | GPSLongitude = 123,56.41529555E
  | - Tag 'x:xmpmeta/rdf:RDF/rdf:Description/exif:GPSLongitude'
...


That means the ISO container has

an uuid atom which identifies as XMP,

which is just plain XML that needs to be parsed for the GPS details. And we also see someone used ExifTool right away to write this metadata to the file.





Exif and XMP are two different formats - don't confuse every metadata format as Exif.

ExifTool has its name for historic reasons, because at first it really only wanted to support Exif, but now it can read many more formats, even propritary ones.

Exif.js claims:

A JavaScript library for reading EXIF meta data from image files.

Get it? Image files. No mention of video containers. And even that is wrong, as it only supports JFIF as picture format. From those, it can not only read Exif, but also XMP and IPTC. It doesn't even try to read from other file formats - not even other picture formats. And (like many) they write Exif wrongly in all uppercase. That library isn't worth much.



Thank you very much for your reply. Simply put, exif-js does NOT support xmp, even though the official page say it DOES support xmp?

No, it does not support anything else than JFIF (vulgo JPEG image) files. If it would support MP4 (video container) files there might be a chance that it could read and parse XMP from those. You haven't read or understood its own description "from image files" - .mp4 is not an image file - it's a video container. The library would first need to understand a whole different file format before being able to detect XMP in it.

Thank you very much for your clarification.

Then what would be the best way to read geolocation info from mp4 files? for example, a quick hack to exif-js to read xmp geo tag (and geo tag only,  not xmp meta data in general, which is, to be honest, above my knowledge).



In addition  exiftool -xmp:gpslatitude=x -xmp:gpslongitude=-y FILE.mp4  would be better to be read by a library such as quickly hacked exif-js, since you mentioned exif tag is mixedly used in xmp section, which might be wrong even though exiftool read correctly?


Note my ultimate goal is to put images AND movies on the google maps by reading geo tags from files. Thank you very much. Have a nice day!

Just find a different library if you can't/won't parse .mp4 on your own. Executing programs (like ExifTool) is not a programming solution - Stack Overflow is about programming. There's no "quick hack", nor would it help to to read "geo tag only, not XMP metadata in general", since XMP is XML, which must be parsed entirely to get any of its content. Consider accepting (that's different from upvoting) my answer.

Thank you for your answer. I am stacked at here to read geo tag from mp4 files. A good practical advice, which moves me forward to my goal mentioned above, will be accepted as an  answer (sorry, AmigoJack);  Preferably with a sample client-side javascript code which reads geo tags from both images AND movies. Anyone, please! Thank you very much! Have a nice weekend :)

@stackunderflow (1) You have a correct Answer from AmigoJack as far as using Exif-js to read MP4 files. The library doesn't do it, and future readers will appreciate to know that. (2) You ask for "advice which moves me forward to my goal..." and he tells you that your data is inside "a uuid atom which identifies as XMP". He is correct. This is how your file looks like inside a hex editor (ie: download a free one or use some online one). The left-side is the bytes (as hex digits) and the right-side is the bytes when processed as text.

@stackunderflow (3) Generally "there is no quick hack" but in this case you might be lucky because XML or XMP themselves are just text formats. Test by opening the file in a text editor (Notepad?). Search the text document for xmp and you should see your required ExifTool text. Now simply extract the same text but using Javascript.  If stuck then ask a new question that focuses on your text extraction from a file. Show your code attempt and someone will help you with a possible fix.
